# Keep Touch listener on XML?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have an XML layout in the background with a transparent SurfaceView on top, how can I pass the touch events through the SurfaceView to the XML?

Here is my onTouch() Listener:

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) 
    {
        //x = me.getX();
        zoomController++;
        Log.d("Tat", String.valueOf(zoomController));
        //y = me.getY();

        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're not using the touch event in `SView`, return `false` from your `onTouch()` method it will reach to lower layouts.

Comment: Your format made me think that the `onTouch()` method immediately below your `SView` class was actually part of `SView`... Hmm, try adding `setClickable(false)` to your `SView` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [OnInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) 
Basicly since you have an surface view on top, and you don't want it to handle the touch event, you return true to take the event from child.

```
    public class ParentContainer extends View {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public ParentContainer (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;//parent gets the touch event
}
```

Comment: So How would I implement this and will it automatically just push it through to the XML, and handle per-say a "Horizontal Scroll View"?

Comment: That didn't do it.  I am trying to make it as if I never had a surfaceView on at all, and I was just directly controlling the setContentView(layout) features...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I have done is just in my onTouch() at the bottom I returned false, and it let me actually work on both canvases: the XML and SurfaceView!

Comment: Ha, this was my original suggestion. :)